# Custom string length function logic error

Tags: c, string, logic

I am creating my own string word length function for an assignment(well it's at least apart of the assignment), but for some reason I am getting a really weird error. It's supposed to give me the number of words within a string, but for some reason the value is not being saved. Even when I run it, it says that the length is 21 for the string, "Happy go lucky charms". Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>       // For the letter checking functions


int findLengthString( char *word){
    int i = 0;
    int length = 0;
    for ( i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++){
        length++;
    }
    printf("length is %d", length );
    return length;   
}


int totalWords(char *str) {

    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int hold = findLengthString(str);

    for ( i = 0; i < hold; i++ ) {

        if ( str[i] == ' ' || str[i+1] == '\0') {
            printf("total is %d", total);
            total++;
    }
    return total;
}

}


int main() {

    int hold = 0;
    char arr[] = "Happy go lucky charms";

    hold = totalWords(arr);


    printf("hold is %d", hold);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return total;` wrong position.

Comment: Oh doe, thank you. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

## include

## include

int totalWords(char str[]) {

```
int i = 0;
int total = 0;
int hold = strlen(str);
```

for ( i = 0; i < hold; i++ ) {

```
   if ( str[i] == ' ' || str[i+1] == '\0') {
        printf("total is %d\n", total);
        total++;
      }
 }    
return total;
```

}

int main() {

```
int hold = 0;
char arr[] = "Happy go lucky charms";

hold = totalWords(arr);


printf("hold is %d", hold);
```

return 0;
}

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that the `return` is in a wrong position. If you format your code properly, you will clearly see what's wrong:

```
int totalWords(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int hold = findLengthString(str);
    for ( i = 0; i < hold; i++ ) {
        if ( str[i] == ' ' || str[i+1] == '\0') {
            printf("total is %d", total);
            total++;
        }
        return total; // <<== You return in the loop
    }
    // You should return here
}
```

However, this is the smaller problem. A bigger problem is that the logic of your code is incorrect: rather than counting words, it counts spaces, so a string like this `"Hello,         world!"` will produce 10 instead of 2.

To fix this problem you need to change your algorithm in such a way that you add `1` to total only if you have seen a non-space after the last increment:

```
int totalWords(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int hold = findLengthString(str);
    int inWord = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < hold; i++ ) {
        if ( str[i] == ' ' || str[i+1] == '\0') {
            total+= inWord;
            inWord = 0;
        } else {
            inWord = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("total is %d", total);
    return total;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Fy8Wo6)